# Touch behavior not behaving the same as pressing A and D

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, touch

so I have this game where you move a car left and right with "A" and "D". I use the following code to do this:
on "A" press:

```
characterBody.AddForce(-moveSpeed, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

on "D" press:

```
characterBody.AddForce(moveSpeed, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

I am now trying to transfer this game to mobile, using touch on both sides of the screen. Here is my code for that, using the same concepts:

```
void Update()
{
    int i = 0;
    //loop over every touch found
    while (i*2 < Input.touchCount)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x > ScreenWidth / 2)
        {
            //move right
            //RunCharacter(1.0f);
            characterBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;

            characterBody.AddForce(moveSpeed, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x < ScreenWidth / 2)
        {
            //move left
            //RunCharacter(-1.0f);
            characterBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            characterBody.AddForce(-moveSpeed, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

When I do this code, no matter how high or low I set the moveSpeed variable, it does not have the same effect. Here is what it is with arrow keys/"A" and "D": https://infinitecarspeeder.netlify.com.  I want it to have that effect, but however it doesn't have the ForceMode.Impulse effect, and is extremely slow to switch directions. Thank you so much!

**EDIT:**

Here's my code that I use for keyboard movement (works fine):

```
void FixedUpdate(){
    transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * forwardSpeed);
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)||Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){

        MoveLeft();
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)||Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){

        MoveRight();
    }
}

public void MoveLeft()
{

    rb.AddForce(-10.75f, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
public void MoveRight()
{

    rb.AddForce(10.75f, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: Your loop is a bit strange ... why not simply `foreach(var touch in Input.touches)` ? Then the difference might simply be `characterBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;` which doesn't allow you to get faster.

Comment: @derHugo Is it the loop which is wrong, the velocity is unnecessary...

Comment: Could you add the code you are currently using with the keyboard so we can compare?

Comment: @derHugo Sorry for the delay, wasn't able to get to my computer. I have re-edited my question to add the code for keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

When using the keyboard, do you reset the character velocity to 0? That may make a difference in feeling if you don't. If you reset the velocity to zero at each update the max speed the car can move is 1.0f since it cannot accelerate. If you don't, the car can move faster than only 1.0f which would explain the difference in speed.

Comment: No, I do not set the velocity to 0. I set it on touch because it does not apply enough force the other way, for example, if I am holding d down, and hold a for like a little longer, it will change directions easily. This does not happen on mobile. If you have another solution, please tell me!

Comment: Hey, did you find something out? @KnackKnack